# Pip Downloads Failing with Mis-Matched Hashes

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, pip

I'm asking this question here as I'm almost sure this is a network issue rather than a pip issue....

I do a lot of work with virtual environments, pip and python on my Mac and in Linux VMs on the same Mac.

Almost the first step is downloading the project requirements with pip: `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

For the last four days or so, the packages (ranging in size from a few Kbs to a few MBs) have been downloading at a good speed, then suddenly failing with an error like this:

`Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-   1.9.1.tar.gz#md5=07e09df0adfca0b2d487e39a4bf2270a (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/) (<md5 HASH object @ 0x2abf260>) doesn't match the expected hash 07e09df0adfca0b2d487e39a4bf2270a!`

The errors seem to occur randomly - sometimes the package downloads fine, sometimes it fails and always at different percentages (of completion). The problem exists for a variety of different packages and on my Mac and the various Linux VMs which I use.

I have a 4MB ADSL connection (uncapped but shaped) with a wireless LAN.

I'd be very grateful if anyone can suggest where the problem might be occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: what versions of `pip` and python are you using? Have you tried [installing the latest version](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html)?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of pip and python 2.7.2

Comment: Same here, I had problems with getting numpy. The second time I tried, it worked. Maybe a glitch in pypi today? The same hashes in the error are weird though.

Comment: It's been like this for me for a few days now. Others I work with (in other parts of the world) have had no issues, so I'm guessing pypi is not the issue. But yes, the fact that the hashes are the same is odd....